# Linq query returning null with custom ConfigurationElementCollection implementing IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, configuration

I have a custom `ConfigurationElementCollection` called `EnvironmentElementCollection` to configure my different environments within a class library I'm writing.  I have a static property in a class to get a collection of all the environments that are listed in that section.  There is a property of the contained items (`EnvironmentElement`) that indicates the environment is a "login" environment.  My goal is to be able to filter the collection with Linq to get only the "login" environments, but the Linq query always returns null.  I implemented `IEnumerable` using [this](http://blog.davidtruxall.com/2010/06/02/using-linq-against-a-custom-configurationelementcollection/) tutorial, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Configuration Classes

```
public class EnvironmentSection : ConfigurationSection {

    private static ConfigurationPropertyCollection properties;
    private static ConfigurationProperty propEnvironments;

    static EnvironmentSection() {
        propEnvironments = new ConfigurationProperty(null, typeof(EnvironmentElementCollection), null, ConfigurationPropertyOptions.IsDefaultCollection);
        properties = new ConfigurationPropertyCollection { propEnvironments };
    }

    protected override ConfigurationPropertyCollection Properties {
        get {
            return properties;
        }
    }

    public EnvironmentElementCollection Environments {
        get {
            return this[propEnvironments] as EnvironmentElementCollection;
        }
    }
}

public class EnvironmentElementCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection, IEnumerable<EnvironmentElement> {
    private static ConfigurationPropertyCollection properties;

    public EnvironmentElementCollection() {
        properties = new ConfigurationPropertyCollection();
    }

    protected override ConfigurationPropertyCollection Properties {
        get {
            return properties;
        }
    }

    public override ConfigurationElementCollectionType CollectionType {
        get {
            return ConfigurationElementCollectionType.BasicMap;
        }
    }

    public EnvironmentElement this[int index] {
        get {
            return (EnvironmentElement)base.BaseGet(index);
        }
    }

    public EnvironmentElement this[string name] {
        get {
            return (EnvironmentElement)base.BaseGet(name);
        }
    }

    protected override string ElementName {
        get {
            return "add";
        }
    }

    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement() {
        return new EnvironmentElement();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element) {
        var elm = element as EnvironmentElement;
        if (elm == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
        return elm.Name;
    }

    //for implementing IEnumerable
    public new IEnumerator<EnvironmentElement> GetEnumerator() {
        int count = base.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            yield return (EnvironmentElement)base.BaseGet(i);
        }
    }
}

public class EnvironmentElement : ConfigurationElement {
    private static ConfigurationPropertyCollection properties;
    private static ConfigurationProperty propLoginEnabled;

    public EnvironmentElement() {                
        propLoginEnabled = new ConfigurationProperty("loginEnabled", typeof(bool), null, ConfigurationPropertyOptions.None);
        properties = new ConfigurationPropertyCollection { propLoginEnabled };
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("loginEnabled")]
    public bool LoginEnabled {
        get {
            return (bool)base[propLoginEnabled];
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my class to get environments:

```
public class Environment {

    //Works fine to get all environments
    public static EnvironmentElementCollection All {
        get {
            EnvironmentSection dls = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("environments") as EnvironmentSection;
            return dls.Environments;
        }
    }

    //Returns null
    public static EnvironmentElementCollection Login {
        get {
            EnvironmentSection dls = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("environments") as EnvironmentSection;

            EnvironmentElementCollection envs = dls.Environments.Where<EnvironmentElement>(e => e.LoginEnabled == true) as EnvironmentElementCollection;
            return envs;
        }
    }
}
```

So I can't tell which part is breaking, if my implementation of IEnumerable is bad, or my Linq query, or something else.

Comment: This looks like an issue with your final cast. Try removing the `as EnvironmentElementCollection` and replacing the `EnvironmentElementCollection envs = ...` with `var envs = ...`. What type does it try to resolve to?

Comment: `envs = {System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator<WLGore.Configuration.EnvironmentElement>}`

Comment: I guess that makes sense, try adding a `.ToEnumerable()` right before the `as EnvironmentElementCollection`.

Comment: It doesn't look like I have that option

Comment: Are you able to get the EnvironmentSection list (dls) in the Login property?

Comment: Did you get any solution? I am getting the same error :(